# How to use Baler for JS bundling on Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2.3, jsbundling, magento-cloud, advanced-bundling, baler

[Baler](https://github.com/magento/baler) is great for JS bundling comparing to default JS bundling.

It's hard to apply it to a Magento Cloud instance as Magento Cloud is a read-only system. So we can't run npm command directly via SSH access following [their document](https://github.com/magento/baler/blob/master/docs/ALPHA.md)

Is there a way to apply Baler to a Magento Cloud instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install Baler on Magento Cloud for my client.

All we need to do is to update the build hook in [.magento.app.yaml](https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud/blob/2.3.4/.magento.app.yaml#L76). Below is the detail for the steps that I did:

1. Upgrade node to version 14.4.0 by updating the build hook before the static is generated in [.magento.app.yaml](https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud/blob/2.3.4/.magento.app.yaml#L78)

   unset NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX

   curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | dash

   export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

   nvm current

   nvm install 14.4.0
2. Install AMD baler module following [their doc](https://github.com/magento/baler/blob/master/docs/ALPHA.md) before the static is generated in [.magento.app.yaml](https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud/blob/2.3.4/.magento.app.yaml#L78)

   git clone https://github.com/magento/baler.git

   cd baler

   npm install

   npm test

   npm run build

   npm link

   cd ..
3. Run baler command after the static is generated in [.magento.app.yaml](https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud/blob/2.3.4/.magento.app.yaml#L79)
4. Minify JS files using Terser after Baler is run after the static is generated in [.magento.app.yaml](https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud/blob/2.3.4/.magento.app.yaml#L79)

   npm install -g terser

   find 'pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma' \( -name '*.js' -not -name '*.min.js' -not -name 'core-bundle.js' -not -name 'requirejs-bundle-config.js' \) -exec terser \{\} -c -m reserved=['$','jQuery','define','require','exports'] -o \{\} \;
5. Install module [Magento_Baler](https://github.com/magento/m2-baler)
6. Disable default JS minification, JS merging, JS bundling and enable Baler JS bundling by updating [app/etc/config.php](https://prnt.sc/t15hrk)
7. Commit everything and do a git push.

See the final build hook in the following link https://gist.github.com/toan-tam/a5bd795f846fb1243f096648f5bce4f9

Note:

- Remember to replace your theme location in the pub folder in step #4
- If you have issues with the steps above, try to apply them one by one and then do a git push to confirm which step is broken and then fix it.

Reference doc:

- https://github.com/magento/baler/blob/master/docs/ALPHA.md
- https://www.integer-net.com/magento-2-javascript-bundling-baler-devtools/

Comment: After enabling baler, product image is not loading in product detail page